# Log http data in unique files using tcpick

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffer, sniffing

I'm trying to use `tcpick` to log http data in unique files (client and server mixed together). This is one of the examples from `tcpick`'s [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpick):

`$ tcpick -i eth0 "port 80" -wRub`

I expected this to write the tcp stream to a file named `<ip_client>_<ip_server>_<port_server>.tcpick`, but it seems that no file gets written at all.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? I'm running `tcpick` 0.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too old to be of help, but ...
My first guess would be that it's not seeing any traffic on eth0 port 80.  If you "tcpdump -i eth0 port 80" do you get any traffic?  If not, how about just "tcpdump -i eth0"?  Answers to those might shed light.

When I run the above command (with appropriate interface name for my system), I get many files created.  tcpick 0.2.1 on FreeBSD 9.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark. IIRC, I did make sure there was traffic on port 80. I have since picked [Justniffer](http://justifier.sf.net) as my HTTP sniffing tool of choice.

Comment: Cool -- Justniffer looks useful